# How can i calculate the direction vector of a pixel?

Tags: python, c, image-processing

So if you take a pinhole camera and make it as the origin of our plane(3D) and a pixel from the image plane and connect the two with a straight line it should make a vector, which has direction and a length. Think of this as the path followed by the light reflected from an object into the camera lens. And I want to calculate this. I think we have to use the cameras intrinsic properties for this.

Below is a statement that made me think about it all.

> In a pinhole camera model, each pixel defines a direction vector in 3D space, specifically the vector from the projection center through the pixel's position on the image plane.

[Here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Ray_trace_diagram.svg/300px-Ray_trace_diagram.svg.png) is a diagram better explaining this.

[image]

I want to calculate the three red lines, and known parameters would be, I guess, the camera position(origin) and the image pixel value, and the intrinsic camera parameters.

Comment: Are you using C or Python?

Comment: You have tagged it both Python and C, but the question looks like one of Mathematics rather then programming.  Either make it explicitly about programming (and choose one language), or ask at https://math.stackexchange.com/ perhaps.

Comment: For any pixel with three-dimensional position P and a point-size camera at position C, the vector from the camera to the pixel is P−C. An expression for all points on the line defined by that vector is C + (P−C)x, that is, all points obtained by starting at C and traveling any distance in the direction of the vector P−C. (Requiring 0 < x makes it a ray rather than a line.) If the light is affected by other camera parameters, you need to explain those parameters, including saying what the camera model is.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica I am not sure what language to go for. so tagged both. what do you say?